# Unable to obtain Analytical expression for a long integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I have the following parameter `c1` that I wish to integrate analytically (I need a close form expression in order to study them in detail):

```
c1 = ((4 Γ (16 g2^4 + 8 g2^2 (κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2)))/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2))))
```

Where the parameters `g1`, `g2`, `κ1`, `κ2`, `Γ` are all Real and greater than zero (`>0`). `ω` is real but can take on negative values. I want to integrate `c1` with respect to`ω` from `-[\Infinity]` to `[\Infinity]`. Doing:

```
Integrate[c1, {ω, -∞, ∞}]
```

Returns a really long and ugly expression with `root`. I then try to simplify the radicals:

```
Integrate[c1, {ω, -∞, ∞}] // ToRadicals
```

And I'm returned with the radicals evaluated (nicer looking) albeit still extremely long. I then noticed that there was a `ConditionalExpression` so I define my parameters as Reals in the process of evaluating the integral:

```
Evaluate[Integrate[c1, {ω, -∞, ∞}] // ToRadicals, Assumptions -> Γ ∈ Reals, κ1 ∈ Reals, κ2 ∈ Reals, g1 ∈ Reals, g2 ∈ Reals, ω ∈ Reals]
```

And I'm still returned with `ConditionalExpression`. I'm not sure how to work around this to obtain a proper expression in terms of my parameters and I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you prefer radicals? `Root` objects are better behaved. Bronze age math versus space age math...

Comment: What is the path of integration in the vicinity of the six zeroes in the denominator of `c1`, particularly those on the real axis?

Comment: The solution of the integral should be a sum of residues at the six zeroes of the `Denominator` of `c1`.  The square roots of the three `Root` functions appearing in the result of `Integrate` are the values of the zeroes.  Probably, they cannot be simplified except in special cases.  If two zeroes lie on the real axis, probably the Principal Value of the integral should be taken.  I should add that the integration path assumed by `Integrate` in obtaining the answer that it returns is not necessarily correct.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You're right. It seems I will need to use the `Residue` function. What do you mean by the integration path assumed by `Integrate` is not correct? What should be my approach then?

Comment: @kowalski  about to board a plane.  Shall provide an answer this evening.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the question provided by `Integrate` can be simplified by eliminating `ConditionalExpression` but otherwise cannot be simplified much.  It is, however, possible to broaden the applicability of the solution substantially.  To begin, note that `c1` is a quadratic polynomial in `ω^2` divided by cubic polynomial in `ω^2`.  Consequently, the integral can be evaluated by closing the contour of integration at large `Abs[ω]` in the upper half of the complex `ω` plane and then summing the residues of the enclosed poles of `c1`.  Unfortunately, Mathematica 11.3 seems to have difficulty recognizing which poles actually are enclosed.  As noted in the question,

```
s = Integrate[c1, {ω, -∞, ∞}];
```

is too long to be reproduced here.  However, the structure of `s` can be presented succinctly by

```
rts = Cases[s, _Root, Infinity] // Union
```

which returns as `Root` functions the three solutions for `ω^2` from `Denominator[c1] == 0`.  Replacing them in `s` by

```
ss = s /. Root[_, n_] -> rt[n]
(* ConditionalExpression[
    -((I Pi Γ ((4 g2^2 + κ1 κ2)^2 (Sqrt[rt[2]] + Sqrt[rt[3]]) + 16 rt[1] (rt[2] 
    Sqrt[rt[3]] + Sqrt[rt[2]] rt[3]) + Sqrt[rt[1]] ((4 g2^2 + κ1 κ2)^2 + 
    4 (8 g2^2 - κ1^2 - κ2^2) Sqrt[rt[2]] Sqrt[rt[3]] + 16 rt[2] rt[3])))/
    (16 Sqrt[rt[1]] (Sqrt[rt[1]] + Sqrt[rt[2]]) Sqrt[rt[2]] (Sqrt[rt[1]] + 
    Sqrt[rt[3]]) (Sqrt[rt[2]] + Sqrt[rt[3]]) Sqrt[rt[3]])), 
    Im[Sqrt[rt[1]]] < 0 && Im[Sqrt[rt[2]]] < 0 && Im[Sqrt[rt[3]]] < 0] *)
```

The condition given is that the three poles `Sqrt[rt[_]]` lie in the lower half of the complex plane.  But, what about the other three poles, given by `- Sqrt[rt[_]]`?  Now consider a specific solution, obtained by direct integration.

```
Integrate[c1 /. {g1 -> 1, g2 -> 7, κ1 -> 3, κ2 -> 4, Γ -> 5}, {ω, -∞, ∞}]
N[%]
(* (10220 Pi)/5247 *)
(* 6.11913 *)
```

But, applying this to the general solution yields

```
s /. {g1 -> 1, g2 -> 7, κ1 -> 3, κ2 -> 4, Γ -> 5}
(* Undefined *)
```

Why `Undefined` is returned can be seen from

```
Sqrt@N[rts /. {g1 -> 1, g2 -> 7, κ1 -> 3, κ2 -> 4, Γ -> 5}]
(* {0. + 2.4901 I, 7.06613 - 1.75495 I, 7.06613 + 1.75495 I} *)
```

The first and third roots are in the upper half plane, and the second in the lower half.  To obtain the correct solution, discard the `ConditionalExpression` and choose the poles in the upper half plane.

```
N[s[[1]] /. Sqrt[Root[z_, n_]] :> Sign[Im[Sqrt[Root[z, n]]]] Sqrt[Root[z, n]] 
    /. {g1 -> 1, g2 -> 7, κ1 -> 3, κ2 -> 4, Γ -> 5}] // Chop
(* 6.11913 *)
```

(`FullSimplify` cannot obtain the compact exact value, `(10220 Pi)/5247` in a reasonable amount of time, but the corresponding numerical values agree to any number of significant figures.)  Note that the substitution above does not work for `Im[Sqrt[Root[z, n]]] == 0`. Although modest changes would accommodate purely real poles, they appear to be rare for `c1`.  To be precise, I have found none despite diligently searching.